# Error while adding Foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I am using Mysql Workbench. I have already made the table.
Now I want to add foreign key in a table called `Personal_Details` that key is primary key in `Login` table.

But when I am trying to do so, it shows me the following error:

```
ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'shaadiDB.#sql-404_25' (errno: 121)
```

SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `shaadiDB`.`Personal_Details` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Login_Id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`Login_Id` )
  REFERENCES `shaadiDB`.`Login` (`Login_Id` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
, ADD INDEX `Login_Id` (`Login_Id` ASC)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*It is happening frequently*"? Are you altering the table structure so frequently?

Comment: No, i am not altering table frequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before adding any constrain to a table that already have some data might cause this problem,try to add constrain with out data

Comment: The posted error was not due to data duplication but key name duplication.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the table `Personal_Details` is having data from which there might be some rows with Login_Id for which entry is not present in table `Login`.

If this is the case , then solution would be that you need to move the data to another table, then add constraint. After adding the constraint you need to add all rows back to table 1 by 1.

Comment: I can't select the index column...why its happening?!

Comment: @AM26 Am really surprised that what made you reconsidering the accepted answer, as I find no difference between, added that I've explained how can you add Constraint rather than just a general statement

Answer (score 1):

***Error 121***: This error explicitly is thrown when there is a duplication in key names.

Immediately after running your `Alter ...` statement, execute the following and observe the results.

```
SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS;
```

Description text from the result will tell you on which key name the duplication is found.
Based on that you modify your `ALTER ...` statement and execute.

Alternatively you can also find if any such duplicate key name is defined by executing:

```
select constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name
from information_schema.table_constraints
where table_schema = DATABASE() -- and constraint_type = 'foreign key'
```

Constraint types can be anything like `PRIMARY KEY`, `FOREIGN KEY`, etc.

If you see any key names in the result that you are trying to use in your `ALTER ..` statement, you should modify them and execute.